# implementing with_scope with information from session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

In my various controllers, in various find calls, I will be imposing 1 particular condition:

```
data_owner_id = @current_user.data_owner_id
```

as

1. I want to be DRY and
2. I don't want to risk forgetting adding this to all the finds in all controllers

So I'd like to implement some kind of global scope, with information that feeds from the controller. "scope" cannot be used in the models as (from railsdoc)

> scopes defined with scope will be evaluated when they are defined, rather than when they are used

and the `@current_user` is not defined at that point.

Can anybody throw any ideas on what the DRYest way to handle this is?

Comment: Scopes can be defined with a lambda that accepts a parameter, like the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like this

have a before filter in your controller

Ex:

controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :owner_id


  def owner_id
    @data_owner_id = @current_user.data_owner_id
  end
end
```

By this way you can make sure all your controller methods have the variable @data_owner_id 
Then you can have a scope as @nkm mentioned

HTH

sameera

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of model scope here, eg: if there is a Post model which has an attribute owner_id,

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
   scope :owned, :lambda{|id| where("owner_id = #{id}")}
end
```

and in controller,

```
Post.owned(@current_user.id)
```